# Which database is more suitable for executing user submitted queries?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mongodb

I am in charge of creating a custom reporting tool for the company's clients. The goal is to let the client's in-house/contractor developers to query our database via a web-based query tool.

There are two main concerns here: Having users only *read-only* access to the database -- with no ability to run admin functions via queries, and having every query being async and have a timeout to prevent un/intentional DDoS attacks.

I can choose from *PostgreSQL*, *MongoDB* and *MySQL*, but I'm not expert in any of these. Therefore my question is which of these databases offers:

a) more control over each individual query

b) more sophisticated user-based permissions and access control system

c) and a better built-in performance overload handling in case of many small queries or few huge queries that can potentially crash the database

I understand that I'm mixing NoSQL and RDBMS here, but I'm happy to go for either of these if I can build a more reliable solution in the end.

Also scaling and performance come as lower priorities and can be totally excluded from the comparison.

Comment: for b) the answer is clearly Postgres. For c) most probably Postgres as well, because the query optimizer is a **lot** better. For a) this depends on the definition of "control over the query". If you are talking about what you can do with the database,  Postgres' [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) capabilities are far ahead of MySQL's

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Great! I will look them up! If you don't mind posting it as an answer I can upvote at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only comment on the (never ending) MySQL vs. Postgres question. I have never used MongoDB.

---

> *more control over each individual query*

Not sure what you mean with that. If that refers to limiting resource consumption then I don't think any of those three products will help you with that.

If that is about the *possibilities* you have when writing queries, then Postgres is the clear choice for that. It has a **lot** more [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) features then MySQL does. My understanding is that MongoDB's aggregation capabilities are still not on the same level as those available in modern relational databases - but I have never used MongoDB so I can't tell.

> *more sophisticated user-based permissions and access control system*

Postgres has definitely the more sophisticated permission systems with user groups and row level security.

> *and a better built-in performance overload handling in case of many small queries or few huge queries that can potentially crash the database*

To my knowledge, neither Postgres nor MySQL have any built-in features to limit resource consumption of individual queries like e.g. Oracle or SQL Server offer (apart from things like global statement timeouts). But as I don't really use MySQL any more there might be something I don't know about.